# Se detectó que tu app usa una versión anterior de la API para desarrolladores de Google Play

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

La consola de google play me muestra la siguiente alerta: "Se detectó que tu app usa una versión anterior de la API para desarrolladores de Google Play. Las versiones 1 y 2 de esta API dejarán de estar disponibles a partir del 1 de diciembre de 2019. Actualízala a la versión 3 antes de esta fecha. Más información"
pero no veo que se utilize esa api.

Comment: Hola Martin, agrega más información por ejemplo tu AndroidManifest.xml y tu google-services.json en caso de tenerlo configurado en tu proyecto, por favor revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Que versión tienes en el build.gradle de la app?